# How to two-way bind a checkbox using Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I currently have an accordion with a bunch of options in the form of checkboxes. The user can select the checkboxes as expected however, I want to already have some of those checkboxes checked depending on certain conditions. The issue is sometimes that is determined after the page has loaded. Below are simplified examples to demonstrate my code (my code is for work and would not be able to share due to confidentiality issues).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div "ngFor="let value of filteredPeople" >
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="selectPeople(value)" [checked]="checkedPeople.get(value)">
      {{ value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

My Javascript:

```
public checkPeople() {
  this.selectedPeople.forEach(element => {
    this.checkedPeople.set(element, true);
  });
}
```

To explain some variables and methods:
Variables:

- filterPeople - a string array of all possible people
- checkedPeople - a map with a KVP of string (the people) and boolean (whether or not their checkbox is checked)
- selectedPeople - a string array of people whose checkboxes I want already checked

Methods:

- selectPeople - checks the corresponding checkbox when user clicks on it
- checkPeople - a method called when I want the specific checkboxes checked (these specific checkboxes change based on other factors so I cannot hard code it)

For some reason my checkPeople method does not seem to select the expected checkboxes, I am not sure why but I have a feeling it is to do with the fact that I have used "[checked]" in the HTML and that it should be something else. Can someone clarify the issue for me and help me identify a fix? (Note: as the title suggests, I am using Angular)

Edit:
I have just debugged my code and added breakpoints, the checkedPeople map has the correct mapping of people to true for each of the elements in selectedPeople which shows that the checkPeople method is working as expected. Therefore the issue must be with the [checked] attribute if I'm not mistaken. I cannot see why it wouldn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[ngModel]="checkedPeople.get(value)"`
instead of `[checked]="checkedPeople.get(value)"`
to initialize the checkbox and

```
(change)="checkUncheckPeople(value, $event)"
```

to update the value when you check or uncheck it, where

```
checkUncheckPeople(value, e) {
   this.checkedPeople.set(value, e.target.value);
}
```

So, in conclusion, your HTML input element will be:

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    [ngModel]="checkedPeople.get(value)" 
    (change)="checkUncheckPeople(value, $event)"
/>
```

If you choose to use an object instead of a map then you can also directly use

```
[(ngModel)]="checkedPeople[value]"
```

to two-way bind the variable

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. There is nothing in the code that determines when the checkboxes are checked.